# Extract value from R output

Tags: r, function, csv, extract

I am wondering how to write the Out of Bag Error (OOB) values below to a csv. They are not included when I type summary(rf). Extracting values from an object summary is the only other approach I have tried and I am out of ideas now. I have also included my write to table function which works with objects.

Code:

```
rf <- tuneRF(x = Pdata[, Imppredictors], y = Pdata[, Response], mtryStart = 1, 
             doBest = TRUE)
mtry = 1  OOB error = 0.6832447 
Searching left ...
Searching right ...
mtry = 2    OOB error = 0.6329592 
0.07359804 0.05 
mtry = 4    OOB error = 0.7310359 
-0.1549495 0.05
```

csv function:

```
write.table(Mse, file = "test1.txt", sep = " ", quote = FALSE, append = FALSE)
```

Comment: Missing: Data and code to load needed packages.

Answer (score 0):

From the [tuneRF documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/randomForest/versions/4.6-12/topics/tuneRF):

> If doBest=FALSE (default), it returns a matrix whose first column contains the mtry values searched, and the second column the corresponding OOB error.

So:

```
rf <- tuneRF(x = Pdata[, Imppredictors], y = Pdata[, Response], mtryStart = 1)
```

And then you can `write.table(rf, ...)`